# Is it important to not place buildings beside avenues?

Tags: simcity-2013

Is it important to not place buildings beside avenues? Why or why not?

Related to this, I also hear a lot regarding roads that branch off slightly from avenues and merge back in to accommodate Bus Terminals, and other Service oriented buildings (I honestly don't know what they're called). How effective are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Update 7, cars may now turn across avenue medians (and full lanes of traffic) while entering and exiting buildings.

It is now reasonable to zone directly on avenues.

Be aware that certain buildings (such as University and both Police buildings) create implicit intersections which allow u-turns.  These u-turns may be disruptive (or helpful!) to traffic flow.

Comment: Hey, but it's the same with roads, even on a dirty road for 2$ a car won't turn left to a building. That's the path of a truck I witnessed: http://i.imgur.com/vCL2RQo.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady But I feel like it's more critical with Avenues since this is where most of your traffic should go, and disrupting your main traffic flow should prove detrimental to the growth of your city.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady cars turning left on a street (even across on-coming traffic). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfRkg49r0kk

Comment: I just performed some tests and noticed many interesting things - two of which are relevant here: 1. Cars turn left also on avenues and go through medians! 2. At least one car type don't make left turns - a moving truck: http://i.imgur.com/wygDthY.png

Comment: when you have a dirt road from an avenue (as in your picture) a median crossing is created.  This is just like an intersection.